# How to fit 5 columns in StackLayout without going out of the frame using xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

I want to put 5 columns together in StackLayout without going out of the frame. In iPhone 12Pro Max everything is ok, but in Iphone 8 things don't look good.

[image: iPhone8 Simulator]

My Code:

```
<Frame
                   BorderColor="White"
                   Margin="10,0,10,0"
                   CornerRadius="10"
                   HasShadow="True"
                   BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                 <RelativeLayout>
        <Image
            x:Name="ImageDescriptionForecast1"
            Aspect="AspectFill"
            RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                                                   Property=Height,
                                                                   Factor=1}"
            RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                                                  Property=Width,
                                                                  Factor=1}"/>
        <StackLayout>
                    <Label x:Name="DateTimeForecast1"
                               Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                               VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                               VerticalOptions="Center"
                               FontSize="14"/>
                    <Label x:Name="DateTimeForecast2"
                               Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                               FontSize="14"/>
                    <Grid BackgroundColor="Transparent" 
                      Padding="0,0,0,0"
                          RowSpacing="0"
                          ColumnSpacing="0">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        ........
                        ........
                        </Grid>
                <StackLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
         </Frame>
```

I tried to put "auto" on ColumnDefinition Width = "auto" but this not work for me.
Is there a way to fit them on display ?

Comment: s StackLayout will expand as needed to fit the size of its children

Comment: What is the alternative to assemble the 5 columns of the smaller display  ?

Comment: How about using a Grid? Ah wait you are doing that. Anyways, change the StackLayout parent to something else. StackLayout expands as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we check document [Xamarin.Forms Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid),we will find that

[image]

So when the size of the item in the grid is large enough, it will take up a lot of space in the space even if we set value `auto` to `ColumnDefinition` .

If we want the items in the same row take up  the same space, we usually set `*` for `ColumnDefinition`. In this condition, if a row have many items and a single item take up a lot of space , all elements in a row will not be fully displayed on the screen.

In this condition, we need to adjust the `HeightRequest` and `WidthRequest` of the item.

For example:

```
   <Frame Grid.Row="0"  
          HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30"
          BackgroundColor="Yellow"
         <Grid.Column="0">
            <Image Source="watermelon.png" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                   VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Aspect="AspectFill" />
   </Frame>
```

For some mobile desktop applications, if there are more columns, each item will be resized to a smaller size. Similarly, if there are fewer columns, then each item will be resized to a larger size.